# Nested self join and creating multiple sums

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a basic parent / child scheme for expenditures:

[image]

The underling data is the same so I just added a category column and parent_id.  These have child records:

[image]

I am trying to aggregate the totals form the orders, related orders and difference between the two like this:

[image]

Which is grouped by the orders overall then I am also looking for something like this:

[image]

I can get the order_amount no problem either way.  That's a simple JOIN and SUM.

I am stuck on the secondary JOINS given that I have to JOIN the invoices expenditures to the orders then JOIN the invoice expenditure items and SUM that up.

I am looking for direction on the correct JOIN or if there is a better way to approach this with some sort of subquery etc.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sump up by order, one solution would be to use a conditional aggregate query. A trick is to check the `category` to decide whether to use the value from column `expenditures.id` or from column `expenditures.parent_id` as grouping criteria:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN e.id ELSE e.parent_id END expenditure_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) order_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'invoice' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) order_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'invoice' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) balance
FROM expenditures e
LEFT JOIN expenditure_items i ON e.id = i.expenditure_id
GROUP BY CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN e.id ELSE e.parent_id END
ORDER BY expenditure_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6f8c1iZZRbf2aH14Fr6Mp/0)**:

```
| expenditure_id | order_amount | order_amount | balance |
| -------------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------- |
| 1              | 3740         | 0            | 3740    |
| 2              | 11000        | 9350         | 1650    |
```

---

The second query, that sums up by item code, basically follows the same logic, but groups by idem code instead:

```
SELECT
    i.code,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) order_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'invoice' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) order_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'order' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN e.category = 'invoice' THEN i.amount ELSE 0 END) balance
FROM expenditures e
LEFT JOIN expenditure_items i ON e.id = i.expenditure_id
GROUP BY i.code
ORDER BY i.code;
```

**[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6f8c1iZZRbf2aH14Fr6Mp/1)**:

```
| code | order_amount | order_amount | balance |
| ---- | ------------ | ------------ | ------- |
| a    | 13400        | 8500         | 4900    |
| b    | 1340         | 850          | 490     |
```

Comment: That's perfect - I had no idea you could do that in the SELECT.

Comment: I was going to roll back the acceptance but I realize now that I didn't articulate my question properly.  I need the difference on a per expenditure basis.  For example I could have orders with no invoices and vice versa.  It's pretty messy and I may just break it up into two separate queries - one for the orders and one for the invoices.